# Input box to select worksheet and column

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a macro on one workbook, I want to make a macro that pops up asking me to select the workbook and the range for it to do something else.

The workbook name and range i need will be different on each workbook that i use it on hence why i need it to have the input box for selecting.

```
Sub Getsheet()

Dim desiredSheetName As String
desiredSheetName = Application.InputBox("Select any cell inside the target sheet: ", "Prompt for selecting target sheet name", Type:=8).Worksheet.Name
Debug.Print desiredSheetName

MsgBox desiredSheetName

Workbooks(desiredSheetName).Activate

Range("A1") = "TEST"

End Sub
```

This only gets the sheet name and not the workbook name so fails at the activate line.
I need to get The workbook, the name and a selected range.
Im sure this is quite simple but im getting a little stuck.

Thanks for any assistance.

---

**UPDATED**

I mustn't have made this clear enough because I thought my request would be rather simple.

I have one workbook which will house macros that I perform on various CVS files.

I open my masterwork book and the file i am working on i run from a button on the master workbook, a macro.

The macro needs to come up with an input box so it makes it clear, straight forward and simple allowing me to select a range on another workbook.

I then need to run the rest of my code using the selected range from the input box.

All I need is how to obtain the workbook name the sheet name and the range from the selection.

hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: So you have multiple requests... why not create a userform?  Combobox for Workbook, then dependent combobox for sheets in said workbook?

Comment: I just want a straight forward select a range input box to make it simple and easy, essentially i want to click on a range and it get the worksheet, workbook and range all in one by just selecting the range i need

Comment: well, if they're clicking, you can capture the ActiveSheet.Name, the ActiveWorkbook.Name, and Selection.Address, as variables.  Unsure what the input box is helping there.  Are you prompting that via button?

Comment: Also `Workbooks(desiredSheetName).Activate` cannot work. as written (the workbook call is using a sheetname... unless the book/sheet have the same name, you have problems)  You need to call the workbook, then the sheet, similar to what is in the last line of my Answer.

Comment: @cyril I have added an update to my question. The calling the sheet isnt the issue here that was just to highlight i need the full range from what was selected in the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use (similar situation here):

```
Sub test2()
    Dim columnStart As Range
    Dim columnNr As Long
    Dim wbC As Workbook
    Dim wsC As Worksheet
    Dim columnAddress As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set columnStart = Application.InputBox("Select the column with the first key", Default:=Selection.Address(0, 0), Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If columnStart Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set wbC = columnStart.Parent.Parent
    Set wsC = columnStart.Parent
    columnAddress = columnStart.Address
    columnNr = columnStart.Column
    Debug.Print "Workbook: " & wbC.Name & " with worksheet: " & wsC.Name & " & column Address: " & columnAddress & " with column number : " & columnNr
End Sub
```

The range you get has a parent = Worksheet, which also has a parent of its own = Workbook.
My intent of the code was to not make it my active workbook but just get the key-column so I could base the rest of the code on it.

**EDIT:**
To put it more into context for you:

```
Sub Getsheet()

    Dim desiredSheetName As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select any cell inside the target sheet: ", "Prompt for selecting target sheet name", Type:=8)
    desiredSheetName = rng.Parent.Name
    Debug.Print desiredSheetName
    
    MsgBox desiredSheetName
    
    rng.Parent.Parent.Activate 'Workbook
    Range("A1") = "TEST"
    'or without needing to use Activate:
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = rng.Parent.Parent 'isn't really needed here
    Set ws = rng.Parent
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Test"
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is what i need it to do but i don't know how im supposed to incorporate it into my code to get the result i need.

Comment: Edited it, let me know if it's still unclear (try to specify what is unclear still)

Comment: thank you, i have tried to use this and tried to use debug.print wb and debug.print ws and both come back with an error rng also comes back with an error?

Comment: Use `Debug.Print wb.Name` and `Debug.Print ws.Name` instead. Depending of what you want from the range, you'll have to also be more specific.

Comment: them debug lines now work for wb & ws thanks but range, i need whatever was selected from the input box

Comment: Ahhhhh ive got it working with     Debug.Print rng.Address thanks so much ! very much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

So I can see some issues about how you prompt this, but to answer the request for activating the sheet you don't have to do anything... you state that you want someone to click the range, which will put them on that sheet.

If you want to capture the information from a selected cell, then you have a list of options, e.g.:

```
Sub test() 'I have the picture below to show the outputs
    Debug.Print Selection.Address
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

So if you want to call a workbook, you can store those as variables and utilize such that:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rAddress As Range:  rAddress = Selection.Address
    Dim rSheet As Worksheet:  rSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Dim rBook As Workbook:  rBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

Then calls can be `Workbooks(rBook).Sheets(rSheet).Address(rAddress)`.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply but I don't understand where in my code they should be placed.

Comment: I have played around with this and it is not capturing it from the selection it is only capturing the last selected sheet, not what was done on the input box.